# post comments with approval on forum

Tags: users, nodes

i use advanced forum. in permission page and comment module permission i  **dont** set post comments without approval for authenticated user but when authenticated user send post on forum it immediately appear in forum without admin approval.
but if this user add comment for a post it will add to approval list.
why?

**edit**: there is my mistake. when i dont set post comments without approval for authenticated user it works correctly (and user cant post **comments**) however authenticated user can create **forum topic** without approval.? how to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have in mind that a post is a node, so it doesn't behave such as comments and so, it doesn't fall into the same logic.
If you want moderation for posts, you should do something else, maybe playing with rules (and or views) to establish a moderation panel/system.

Comment: So what's your question, I'm a bit confused ! :-)

Comment: sorry. i updated my question.

Comment: Forum topic are nodes. It doesn't have anything to do with comments. If you want node moderation, you can setup rules or use the right module.
I did a moderation system with rules for http://nid-de-poule.be/ and it's flawless !

Comment: thank u. u say "If you want node moderation, you can setup rules". more description please.

Comment: Set 'Publish node' to no by default for the content type 'forum topic'.
Then, create a rule who trigger when a new content is created.
For example, "Send a mail to admin when someone write a content type 'forum post'".
Then create a page or a bloc listing unpublished content and review the content.
You can use VBO to fasten things.